# "in" operator in Smarty?

Tags: smarty, smarty3

Does Smarty3 has the "in" operator that works like [Twig's](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator) one:

```
{% if option in [1, 2, 3] %}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes and no. Smarty does not have its own syntax for this, but you can do it like this:

```
{if in_array("foo", ["bar", "foo"])}
```

Personally I find the in keyword confusing. PHP itself doesn't know it. Javascript, the only other programming language relevant to a template developer, treats the in keyword as `array_key_exists()` rather than `in_array()`. Not sure if I wanted a given template engine to do something different…